# HTML5 <picture> srcset fallback for IE 10 and 11

Tags: css, html

I really want to keep my footer responsive to different devices so I have used the generator from cloudinary.  Here is the HTML5

```
<picture>
<img
sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px"
srcset="
footer_rainbow_fjrr5j_c_scale,w_190.png 190w,
footer_rainbow_fjrr5j_c_scale,w_780.png 780w,
footer_rainbow_fjrr5j_c_scale,w_1190.png 1190w,
footer_rainbow_fjrr5j_c_scale,w_1920.png 1920w"
src="footer_rainbow_fjrr5j_c_scale,w_1920.png"
alt="">
</picture>
```

However according to caniuse.com, it doesn't support IE 10 or 11.

What is the best fallback?  All I can think of so far is using media queries using csswith different breakpoints.  Is there a better way?  I have also tried css cover, width; 100% and contain, but neither are perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already have a fallback. The way you have it setup it should work in IE 10 and 11... both will ignore the sizes and srcset attributes but default to using the src attribute.

I tested the same structure using my images and it presented the default fallback image fine on both IE 10 and 11:

```
<img
sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px"
srcset="
http://www.studioadam.com/codepen/waterfall-wide-1100.jpg  1100w,
         http://www.studioadam.com/codepen/waterfall-wide-550.jpg  550w"
src="http://www.studioadam.com/codepen/waterfall-wide-1100.jpg"
alt="">
```

Alternatively (or if you want to art direct images), you could also use source elements within the picture element:
http://codepen.io/studioadam/pen/pNVNNj?editors=1100

Comment: But will the example with picture and source work on IE? 
caniuse says that's not true!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#Browser_compatibility
https://caniuse.com/#search=picture

Comment: @YevheniiHerasymchuk In the case of IE11, "unsupported" actually just means that it will ignore any `picture` and `source` elements in the markup. As long as you have an `img` with a valid `src` attribute as a child of the `picture`, it should fall back to that as if the other markup wasn't there.